# Positioning content inside DIV

Tags: html, css

I want to align the image to left, then its title then the text below it. 
Here is the [screenshot](https://ibb.co/kKOAH9) of what I want to make.
I have made `DIV` for each content. I dont know if its okay to do that.
I made it, because I ll have more control for individual content.

But I havent ben able to do so.

```css
.howtocontainer {
  height: 1985px;
  width: 1121px;
  background-image: url("//azlily.bex.jp/eccube_1/html/template/default/img/howto/background.png");
}

.firstsection {
  /*background: rgb(255,255,255,0.3);*/
  background: grey;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  top: 300px;
  margin: 0 40px 0 40px ;
}

.firstpic {
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.firstsecbanner {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 500px;
  margin-top: -15px;
}
```

```html
<div class ="howtocontainer">

  <div class="firstsection">

    <div class="firstpic">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/462118/pexels-photo-462118.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350">
    </div>
    <div class="firstsecbanner">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/462118/pexels-photo-462118.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350">
    </div>
    <div class="firstsectext">
      お好みの量（目安はピンポン玉大です）を手に取って、パートナーの性感帯を指の腹や手のひらで優しくマッサージ<br>
      してください。<br>
      最初は背中や首筋、そして胸などと、段々と敏感な部分へ伸ばしていくと、ヌルヌルと滑る感覚が気持ちよく、エロ<br>
      ティックな気分を高めることができます。<br><br>

      性感帯は塗った部分が敏感になり、ただ触れるだけでも極上の気持ち良さ。<br>
      シュチュエーションに合わせてラブローションの香りを変えたりしながら楽しみ方を<br>
      見つけてください。
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="secondsection"></div>
  <div class="thirdsection"></div>

</div>
```

---

All I did was Included image and text in one `DIV` 
But gave a class to image by `<img class="class" src"path" >` 
Then I did `float:left` to `.img class`.

Comment: I think you should use absolute path to have your images display successfully.

Comment: In other words, in your `img src` attribute, use the full URL so we can see the image too.

Comment: @BobRodes Sorry. I edited the main post. Added full url

Comment: Use two backslashes at the beginning of each image URL. Example: `//azlily.bex.jp/some/path.jpg`

Comment: @DavidVaughan :/ I dont know what that does ?

Comment: A full HTTP URL is denoted as either secure or not, hence `https://example.com/` versus `http://example.com/`. Two forward-slashes in a `src` or `href` value, followed by their path, indicate the browser to choose the request method. So if a user is viewing your site at `https://example.com/` then the `img src` of `//example.com/some/path.jpg` would load over `https`.

Comment: @DavidVaughan DONE SIR. Edited!

Comment: Still can't see your images when I run the code. Maybe because they aren't available on a secure server? (I can navigate to http://azlily.bex.jp/eccube_1/html/template/default/img/howto/01.jpg in a browser, but I tried editing your post to add the `http:` in front of your `src` value, and still can't see it.)

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 key points that you should notice about using `float`:

- Float container should be set a specific width (absolute or relative width)
- `clear` all floating items

You should change your HTML structure a little bit, and add some CSS styles:

```css
   
.firstpic {
  float: left;
  width: 300px; /*this width is equal with its image's width */
}

.description {
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% - 300px);
}

/* Clear floating item */
.firstsection::after {
  display: table;
  content: "";
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
  <div class="firstsection">
    <div class="firstpic">
      <img src="the-image-on-left-side">
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      <div class="firstsecbanner">
        <img src="the-title-image-on-top">
      </div>
      <div class="firstsectext">
        お好みの量（目安はピンポン玉大です）を手に取って、パートナーの性感帯を指の腹や手のひらで優しくマッサージ<br>
        してください。<br>
        最初は背中や首筋、そして胸などと、段々と敏感な部分へ伸ばしていくと、ヌルヌルと滑る感覚が気持ちよく、エロ<br>
        ティックな気分を高めることができます。<br><br>

        性感帯は塗った部分が敏感になり、ただ触れるだけでも極上の気持ち良さ。<br>
        シュチュエーションに合わせてラブローションの香りを変えたりしながら楽しみ方を<br>
        見つけてください。
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Please add absolute URL instead of relative URL to see your pictures. 
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

A disadvantage of using floats is that it disturbs the natural document flow. You may want to consider an alternative using [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex).

```css
.firstsection {
  display: flex;
}

.firstpic {
  width: 300px;
  /*this width is equal with its image's width */
}

.description {
  width: calc(100% - 300px);
}
```

```html
<div class="howtocontainer">
  <div class="firstsection">
    <div class="firstpic">
      <img src="//azlily.bex.jp/eccube_1/html/template/default/img/howto/01.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      <div class="firstsecbanner">
        <img src="//azlily.bex.jp/eccube_1/html/template/default/img/howto/firstsecbanner.png">
      </div>
      <div class="firstsectext">
        お好みの量（目安はピンポン玉大です）を手に取って、パートナーの性感帯を指の腹や手のひらで優しくマッサージ<br> してください。
        <br> 最初は背中や首筋、そして胸などと、段々と敏感な部分へ伸ばしていくと、ヌルヌルと滑る感覚が気持ちよく、エロ
        <br> ティックな気分を高めることができます。
        <br><br> 性感帯は塗った部分が敏感になり、ただ触れるだけでも極上の気持ち良さ。
        <br> シュチュエーションに合わせてラブローションの香りを変えたりしながら楽しみ方を
        <br> 見つけてください。
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="secondsection"></div>
  <div class="thirdsection"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to ak you that I have been using padding and margin like 500px, 365 px,, is this normal??? I have been trying to align the item exact a sper client design, and I dont see anyother options than setting margin right left or padding top bottom. But the values are large, some had even reached 1k.

Comment: Those values are exceptional. I'm sure there is a better way to do it but it would require insight into the design and existing code.